# Pushbullet HTTP request

Tags: http, pushbullet

Has anyone tried HTTP request with Pushbullet? I tried with postman but it says HTTP not supported, HTTPS allowed. I got success with HTTPS, but I have seen someone did HTTP request here : https://github.com/tuanpmt/espduino/blob/master/espduino/examples/pushbullet/pushbullet.ino

Can anyone tell me  how to do an HTTP request for pushbullet? any extra header or different API?

let me know.

Comment: voting down doesn't really help or solve a problem.

Answer (score 0):

We don't allow HTTP requests for security purposes.  The code you linked to uses HTTPS (or at least port 443 which will definitely be HTTPS):

```
rest.begin("api.pushbullet.com", 443, true)
```

It's possible for you to avoid using HTTPS by creating a proxy that speaks HTTP to the client and HTTPS to the server (in this case the pushbullet api server).

You state in your question that HTTPS worked for you, might I ask why you don't want to use it?

Comment: arduino doesn't speak in https hence I need to do that